# How to bind Vue data to a dropdown

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am learning Vue, and can't tell what I have done wrong here.  Data is being returned from the server (5 records), but is not getting put into the `<select>`; all I get is a single option that says `{{dept.DName}}`

```
<html>
<head><link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body class="container">
<div>
    <select id="deptList">
        <option v-model="selected" v-for="dept in app.depts" v-bind:value="dept.Did">
            {{dept.DName}}
        </option>
    </select>    
</div>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.3.4"></script>
<script src="Scripts/vue-controller.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Scripts/vue-controller.js contains:

```
var app = new Vue({
    data: {
        el: "body",
        depts: [],
        emps: [],
        selected: ""
    },
    methods: {
        getDepts: function () {
            console.log("I'm a little teapot");  // this appears in the log
            this.$http.get("/Dept/Index").then(function(response) {
                this.depts = response.data;
                console.log(this.depts);  //the expected data does appear in the log
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.log(error.statusText);
                });
        }
    },
    created: function () {          
        this.getDepts();
    }
})
```

I am a C# developer and so I am halfway sure I am messing up the this/that context stuff, but have been unable to figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several issues.

1. `el` is not a data property, it is a root property of the Vue definition object.
2. You should *never* bind to `body`. In fact, Vue will prevent it. Bind to an appropriate element in the content of the body.
3. `v-model` should be on the select.
4. You do not need `app.depts`. All data properties can be referenced by name in the template.

```js
console.clear()

const departments = [
  {Did: 1, DName: "Department 1"},
  {Did: 2, DName: "Department 2"},
  {Did: 3, DName: "Department 3"},
]

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data: {
    depts: [],
    emps: [],
    selected: ""
  },
  methods: {
    getDepts: function () {
      console.log("I'm a little teapot");  // this appears in the log
      this.$http.post("https://httpbin.org/post", departments).then(function(response) {
        this.depts = response.body.json;
      },
      function(error) {
        console.log(error.statusText);
      });
    }
  },
  created: function () {          
    this.getDepts();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.3.4/vue-resource.js"></script>
<div id="app">
      <select  v-model="selected" id="deptList">
        <option v-for="dept in depts" v-bind:value="dept.Did">
            {{dept.DName}}
        </option>
    </select>  
    <hr>
    Selected Department: {{selected}}
</div>
```

Note: I modified the ajax call so that it would work in this environment. Your code for the ajax portion looked fine assuming you are using VueResource.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in template are scoped to "app" automatically, so you need to remove "app." from your template, so it will be

```
<select id="deptList" v-model="selected">
  <option v-for="dept in depts" v-bind:value="dept.Did">
    {{dept.DName}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: my bad, I just copied it from OP. v-model should be on <select> instead.

Comment: I removed the `app.` and moved the v-model to the `<select>`. While that is closer to correct, the results are the same.

Comment: Did you also corrected errors related to `el`? Moving it from `data` to root of settings object and setting it to something like `#app` instead of body?

Answer (score -1):

item will be known in parent select element!

```
 <select v-model="item.selectedPersonId">
    <option v-for="(item, index) in personList" v-bind:value="item.personId">
          {{ item.personName }}
    </option>
 </select>
```

and js code is :

```
var app = new Vue({
    el : "#elemName" , 
    data : {
          personList : [{personName = "Name1" , personId = "1"} , 
                        {personName = "Name2" , personId = "2"} ] , 
          selectedPersonId : 0
    }
});
```

work for me.thanks for Vuejs.